# Nestjs/cli bash: nest: command not found

Tags: nodejs

al momento de instaltar @nestjs/cli, segun su documentacion, y tratar de utilizarlo se obtiene
bash: nest: command not found
windos 10
node 15
npm 7
he editado las variables de entorno, para tratar de que salga pero no ha funcionado.
que puedo hacer para que funione el cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema fue que se instalo el @nestjs/cli en usuario especifico en windows10
para solvertarlo desinstale :

- nodejs
- angular cli
- netjs
- npm
  Elimine la carpeta de npm ubicada en C:\Users\vduquer\AppData\Roaming\npm
  y volvi a instalar todo con permisos de administrador y de forma global,
  luego agregue el path de npm en las variables de entorno:
- C:\Users\vduquer\AppData\Roaming\npm
- C:\Program Files\nodejs
  las he agregado tanto en variables del sistema como en las variables de mi usuario

reiniciar y listo, me ha solucionado el inconveniente.